# HTML: id have same name as tag

Tags: javascript, html

I had a strange notice regarding my HTML code and I have no explanation for it if anyone can help explain this:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id='div'>dummy</div>
```

When you define the `id` of an element to have the same name as the tag, if you opened the browser console and typed "div" or "form" it would print out the element itself. 

Can anyone explain this ?

Comment: can you show us how you're `printing out the element itself`?

Comment: The fact your IDs are the same as element types is irrelevant. See the duplicate question.

Comment: If you typed "div in the console" it would print:
<div id="div">dummy</div>

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs - http://jsbin.com/pureyipoca/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: @Quentin haha well I just feel stupid now xD

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs — The question is loaded up with red herrings (it doesn't need to be console specific or have ids that are the same as element types) that bury the lead.

Comment: Yeah, I reviewed the question and found out that! Thanks a lot.